# Angular 2 observable-subscribe showing undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular-http

I am having the same challenge as was faces in the SO Post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761439/angular2-http-using-observables-subscribe-showing-data-undefined) I am getting undefined in the subscribe method in my component.ts, even though in my service i have the data. 
See codes below
p.component.ts

```
 private getPayItems():void{
    console.log('In getPayItems');
    this._payItemService.getPayItems()
    .subscribe(data => { 
        this.payItemArray = data;
        console.log(data);
    },
    (error:any) =>{
         this.alerts.push({ msg: error, type: 'danger', closable: true }); 
    }) 
}
```

p.service.ts

```
getPayItems():Observable<Payitem[]>{

    let  actionUrl = this.url +  "/GetPayItem";

    return this._http.get(actionUrl, { headers: this.headers })
        .map((response: Response) => { 
            <Payitem[]>response.json() ;
             console.log(<Payitem[]>response.json()); //This logs the Object
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you used `{}` it needs explicit return from `function`. So you have to return `<Payitem[]>response.json()` from `map` function.

```
getPayItems():Observable<Payitem[]>{

    let  actionUrl = this.url +  "/GetPayItem";

    return this._http.get(actionUrl, { headers: this.headers })
        .map((response: Response) => { 
             console.log(<Payitem[]>response.json()); //This logs the Object
            return <Payitem[]>response.json() ;
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Otherwise below would be shorthand syntax

```
getPayItems():Observable<Payitem[]>{
    let  actionUrl = `${this.url}/GetPayItem`;
    return this._http.get(actionUrl, { headers: this.headers })
        .map((response: Response) => <Payitem[]>response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: You just saved my day, sir ! Thank you