# Angular 2 - Get Headers From Http Requests

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-http

All my Backend API requests return new token information in headers, even when them throw exceptions. In the next request I need to send these new token information.

So I'm trying to figure out an unique and standard way to do that, so I'm trying:

```
let requestOptions = new RequestOptions(Object.assign({
      method: method,
      url: environment.apiHost + url,
      body: body,
      headers: authenticatedRequest ? this.requestService.getAuthHeaders() : this.requestService.getJsonHeaders(),
      withCredentials: authenticatedRequest
    }));

this.http.request(new Request(requestOptions))
        .map((res:Response) => { this.storageService.setAuthInfo(res.headers); res.json() } )
        .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
```

The problem I'm facing with is that when I `subscribe` to this method, `res` variable is returning `undefined`.

What do you suggest me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you have to return a response `res.json()` explicitly from your `map` function as you used `{}`.

```
this.http.request(new Request(requestOptions))
   .map((res:Response) => { 
       this.storageService.setAuthInfo(res.headers); 
       return res.json();
   } )
   .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
```

Similar [**answer here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40747968/2435473)

Comment: It solved the related problem, but I'm facing a new one: When an error happens, it is not passing by map(), so it doesn't register new tokens. The solution would be set new token (`this.storageService.setAuthInfo(res.headers);`) on catch() also unless there is a request method which is called on success and error return. Any idea?

Comment: @PaspRuby I'd say its worth opening new question, other people can also jump in with thoughts..

Comment: Ok, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769737/angular-2-http-request-method-which-is-called-on-both-success-and-error-cases @Pankaj Parkar