# Angular 2 - Http request method which is called on both success and error cases

Tags: angular, angular2-http

All my Backend API requests return new token information in headers, even when them throw exceptions. In the next request I need to send these new token information.

So I'm trying to figure out an unique and standard way to do that:

```
let requestOptions = new RequestOptions(Object.assign({
  method: method,
  url: environment.apiHost + url,
  body: body,
  headers: authenticatedRequest ? this.requestService.getAuthHeaders() : this.requestService.getJsonHeaders(),
  withCredentials: authenticatedRequest
}));

this.http.request(new Request(requestOptions))
    .map((res:Response) => this.storageService.setAuthInfo(res.headers))
    .catch((error:any) => this.storageService.setAuthInfo(res.headers));
```

For now I have to set new token in map and catch methods. Is there a method which is called both on success and error cases where I could set new token info (`this.storageService.setAuthInfo(res.headers)`) ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.finally` over observable, but by using `finally` function you are not going to get control over `response` stuff. So better have `map` function on observable & from there take `headers` information to some variable. Then pass on that from `finally`'s `this.storageService.setAuthInfo` method call.

**Code**

```
myRequest(){
    let header;
    this.http.request(new Request(requestOptions))
        .map((res:Response) => { 
           //take headers to pass it when request succeed/fails
           header = res.headers;
           return res.json();
        )
        .finally(() => this.storageService.setAuthInfo(headers))
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. headers variable is undefined on .finally(). I guess map method is invoked only on success return.